# Directive scope attribute injection behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I want to do is pass in a JavaScript key code (in my snippet I'm using 13 which is the enter/return key) but the second directive in my example below does not work as expected.

For some reason when I inject scope attributes, the function passed into the directive is not evaluated. The working example (the first directive) has no scope injection and it works fine.

Is this intended behavior? or am I doing something incorrectly?

```js
angular.module('taskLister', []);

angular.module('taskLister')
  .controller('ListController', ListController);
ListController.$inject = ['$log'];

angular.module('taskLister')
  .directive('keyPresser', keyPresser);
keyPresser.$inject = ['$log'];

angular.module('taskLister')
  .directive('keyPresserNotWorking', keyPresserNotWorking);
keyPresserNotWorking.$inject = ['$log'];



function ListController($log) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.editingListTitle = false;
  vm.editListTitle = editListTitle;
  vm.finishedEditListTitle = finishedEditListTitle;

  function editListTitle() {
    vm.editingListTitle = true;
    $log.info('editing');
  }

  function finishedEditListTitle() {
    vm.editingListTitle = false;
    $log.info('finished editing');
  }

}

//********
//Working
//********
function keyPresser($log) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('keydown keypress', function(event) {

        if (event.which === 13) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.$eval(attrs.keyPresser);
          });
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  };

}

//********
//Not Working
//********
function keyPresserNotWorking($log) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      key: '@key'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('keydown keypress', function(event) {

        scope.key = Number(scope.key);

        if (event.which === scope.key) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.$eval(attrs.keyPresserNotWorking);
          });
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="taskLister">


  <div ng-controller="ListController as vm">

    has the user pressed enter? - {{vm.editingListTitle}}
    <br/>

    <input type="text" key-presser="vm.editListTitle()" placeholder="Press Enter">
    <br/>

    <input type="text" key-presser-not-working="vm.editListTitle()" key="13" placeholder="Press Enter but it doesnt work">
    <br/>

    <button ng-click="vm.finishedEditListTitle()" type="button">Reset</button>
    <br/>

  </div>


</div>
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you encapsulated your code doing

`scope: {
    key: '@key'
 },`

just add your `key-presser-not-working` attribute as part of your scope

`scope: {
    key: '@key',
    keyPresserNotWorking: '&'
 },`

and then call it using `scope.keyPresserNotWorking()` at your link method.

Final code.

```js
function keyPresserNotWorking($log) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      key: '@key',
      keyPresserNotWorking: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('keydown keypress', function(event) {

        scope.key = Number(scope.key);

        if (event.which === scope.key) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.keyPresserNotWorking();
          });
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  };

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!